# How to show balance in the view

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show balance in the view, that is, there is a column called Balance in user table and I would like to display the value of that column in the view. Please guys spare me some time The view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Personal Finance</h1>
<p class="p-2 text-dark" >Balance:{{Form::label($balance)}}</p>
<a href="/personal/create" class="btn btn-primary">Create</a>
<br>
@stop
```

The controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $user=User::find($user_id);
        $balance=$user->balance;
        return view('personal.index', compact('personal','balance'));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use

```
public function index()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $user=User::findOrFail($user_id);
        return view('personal.index', compact('personal','user'));

    }
```

Then add this line in the view file

```
<p>{{$user->balance}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are doing a mistake. You are searching a logged in user twice**

First change this

`$user_id=auth()->user()->id;
 $user=User::find($user_id);`

to `$user=auth()->user()` because it will give you logged in user

**Then add this line in the blade view:**

```
<p>{{$balance}}</p>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. you were searching logged user twice.